# Disable Elm form submission without no-op message

Tags: html, forms, form-submit, elm, onsubmit

I have an Elm app with an HTML form (containing an input field and a submit button) that I would like to disable while the input is not valid. I've managed to do that by binding form submission to a no-op message when the input is invalid:

```
type Msg
    = Input String
    | Submit
    | Noop

viewForm : Model -> Html Msg
viewForm = form [ onSubmit (if model.valid then Submit else Noop) ]
    [ input [ onInput Input ] []
    , button [ disabled (not model.valid) ] [ "Submit" ]
    ]
```

`update` then does nothing on a `Noop` message. The button is also disabled, but this is secondary, since I also care about form submission by hitting Enter from the text input. Note that it does not work to skip the `onSubmit` handler, because then hitting Enter will reload the page.

This feels a bit messy and inefficient, so my questions are:

1. What is the idiomatic way to achieve this in Elm?
2. How much more expensive is this use of a no-op message to a no-op Javascript event handler.

Comment: what about using `disabled` attribute? `button [disabled (not model.valid)] [ "Submit" ]`

Comment: @IgorDrozdov Disabling the button doesn't seem to disable form submission via hitting Enter in the input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I have to say that your implementation is alright, there's no harm in sending `Noop` message, that's why it exists.

The best scenario would be to remove the listener entirely(if possible) and disable the button visually. This actually might have a performance drawback if `model.valid` changes super-frequently.

I'm using a helper for conditionally adding stuff to a list:

```
appendIf : Bool -> a -> List a -> List a
appendIf flag value list =
    if flag == True then
        list ++ [ value ]
    else
        list
```

So you could use it like that:

```
view model =
  button
    ([ type_ "" submit ] |> appendIf model.valid (onClick Submit))
    []
```

Comment: I've updated the question to disable the button (which I did locally, just hadn't included in the example). Can you clarify what you mean by saying that `Noop` exists? Is it a common idiom? And note that if the `onSubmit` handler is removed, the default HTML form behaviour causes a page reload.

Comment: @robx my personal preference is to avoid elements with some special behavior, like `<submit>`, while it's semantically correct, it's no longer required thanks to aria attributes. `NoOp` message is a general thing used in many Elm apps, it's totally fine to have it.